# Broadcom BCM57810 iSCSI offload performance

Tags: redhat, iscsi

Anyone out there doing iSCSI offloading using Broadcom BCM57810 10 gigabit ethernet cards?

### My test scenario

### Network....

2 x Dell Force 10 S4810 switches

### Client....

1. Dell R620
2. 24 core
3. 128gb memory
4. 2 Broadcom BCM57810 10 gigabit dual-port ethernet cards.  Only 1 port on each card wired.
5. CentOS 5.9
6. iSCSI offload configured.  Two paths, mtu 9000, no vlan tagging
7. multipath configured
8. ext3 filesystem
9. irqservice running
10. pid 1 children pinned to cpu 0
11. 4 threads split 50% read/write, 16k block size, 4 1gb data files

### Server....

1. Dell Compellent SC8000
2. 8 10gig-e Targets / 4 sessions
3. Tier 1 (Raid 10 write) - 130 15K sas

### Results....

The client drives 400megabytes/sec / 10,000iops.  Switching to software iscsi the client drives 600megabytes/sec / 3200iops.  I tinkered with all sorts of kernel settings with very little effect on throughput.

Broadcom claims 2million iops.  What is going on with this descrepency?  Anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks,

/Chris C

Comment: Are they connected directly?

Comment: Opps.  Forgot about the network switches.  Post updated.

Comment: I am having a similar issue and our Force 10 switches are flooded with pause frames.The Compellent tech recommendations was to switch Windows software initiator with flow control enabled on the server's iscsi interfaces along with jumbo frames and Tcp Delay ack disabled. Have you been able to resolve your issue?

Comment: I had flow control disabled.  

Tcp acl delay is interesting.  I thiiink I adjusted that.  

I never did find out the solution.  I have since moved on to a different company.  New company is focused on 4 node NetApp 8040 c-mode with tcp offload and hardware initiator client side.  If the storage guys come up with something I will post details.